# Firmata over Bluetooth on Arduino?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, bluesmirf, firmata

I have Firmata working fine on an Arduino Uno, communicating over cable USB to Processing.

I want to get rid of the cable, and run the connection over Bluetooth transport (with a BlueSMIRF module). I am unclear on what I need to do to Firmata to tell it to use the BT module rather than the (unconnected) USB cable interface. In particular, do I need to hack Firmata itself to add initialization code which is

1. specific to the BT module I'm using, or
2. more generally, needed to tell Firmata to use a port other than the cabled USB?

Thanks

D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am NOT very good in Firmata, but as i know, Firmata (on arduino) uses 'Serial' (pin 0 and 1, also aka as TX,RX) to communication with the Host. So, if u want to use a BT module to replace your USB cable on the arduino, hack the Firmata to use other pins, other connect the BT to pin 0 and 1.

Comment: why was this the accepted answer? what did you do to get it working? I'm having problems getting my BT serial module to work, and can't find any good information :(

Answer (score 1):

You have to upload standard firmata with baud rate changed to 9600 inside the ino file (or test with other speed rate) and then connect BTooth TX>Rx(uno RX) and the bt RX>Tx(uno TX) as said in the previous post  ,testing it with arduinoCommander worked like a charm!Arduino uno rx tx are pin0 and pin 1.also have it powered not from usb pc but external source cause having the BT ontop while on usb could mess up thing (in general disconnect the ground from BT module while uploading sketches).

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is make sure the USB is connected only when you are uploading your sketches to the arduino and then have the BlueSMIRF connected when you are ready to actually run the Arduino code. This way they will both use the default hardware serial port and you should not have to modify any code.

You could try and use SoftwareSerial.h in the Arduino to emulate another serial port but I have found that to be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Just connect Bluetooth to the Rx Tx pin and upload same standard firmata. Then pass command over bluetooth which you were passing over usb cable....it wil work.